# Confused about the derivation of the x co-ord of the focus in the Lambert solution?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, eccentric-orbit

I'm looking into how the Lambert solution works but there's one bit I'm stuck on. From Wikipedia's [Lambert's problem; Solution for an assumed elliptic transfer orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_problem#Initial_geometrical_analysis) (starting at Eq. 11):

[image]

I don't understand how we can draw the conclusion that $x_0$ is proportional to $r_m$ let alone this value. Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: I see you've included a little bit of [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/284619); it's strongly discouraged to use screenshots of math and text for several reasons, could you write out the material in your image as MathJax as well? Thanks, and *welcome to Stack Exchange!*

Comment: Also, don't worry if this question is closed as off-topic here in Astronomy SE. While it's not about Astronomy *per se*, it is certainly completely on-topic in [Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/) and may be migrated there. There are [almost 200 different SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) to choose from!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question about transfer orbits which is not about Astronomy as defined in the help center. However, it is certainly on-topic in Space Exploration SE and a great candidate for speedy migration.

Comment: You've found one of many Wikipedia articles that are terribly written. The article does however have references.